# Louvain algorithm for graph clustering gives completely different result when running in Spark/Scala and Python, why is that happening?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, cluster-analysis

I am running community detection in graphs made from telecom CDR data. First I was working with very dense graphs containing 10000 nodes, and the algorithm was producing 150 to 170 communities per graph. I was using Louvain community detection algorithm implemented in Scala for Spark.

When I try to run the same algorithm but implemented in C#, I get around 10 communities per graph. I also did some testing with smaller graph, containing around 300 nodes, and same thing occur. When I run it in Spark with Scala I get around 50 communities. When I run it in python or C# I get from 8 to 10 communities.

I am really surprised to see such difference. Every implementation that I used (Scala, Python or C#) is referring to the paper by VD Blondel https://arxiv.org/abs/0803.0476, so the algorithm should be the same, but the output is completely different. Did anyone experienced something like that when using Spark/Scala vs. python/c#?
This is how the main class Louvain is called:

```
import org.apache.spark.graphx.{Edge, Graph}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}

object Driver {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit ={

    val config = LouvainConfig(
      "src/data/input/file_with_edges.csv", //input file
      "src/data/output/",                   //output dir
      1,                                    //parallelism
      2000,                                 //minimumComplessionProgress 
      1,                                    //progressCounter
      ",")                                  //delimiter

    val sc = new SparkContext("local[*]", "Louvain")


    val louvain = new Louvain()
    louvain.run(sc, config)

  }
}
```

This is Scala implementation that I am using:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.io.{Input, Output}
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.serializers.DefaultArraySerializers.ObjectArraySerializer
import com.esotericsoftware.kryo.{Kryo, KryoSerializable}

import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.graphx._
import org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast
//import org.apache.spark.{Logging, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext}

class Louvain() extends Serializable{
  def getEdgeRDD(sc: SparkContext, conf: LouvainConfig, typeConversionMethod: String => Long = _.toLong): RDD[Edge[Long]] = {
    sc.textFile(conf.inputFile, conf.parallelism).map(row => {
      val tokens = row.split(conf.delimiter).map(_.trim())

      tokens.length match {
        case 2 => new Edge(typeConversionMethod(tokens(0)),
          typeConversionMethod(tokens(1)), 1L)
        case 3 => new Edge(typeConversionMethod(tokens(0)),
          typeConversionMethod(tokens(1)), tokens(2).toDouble.toLong)
        case _ => throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid input line: " + row)
      }
    })
  }

  /**
    * Generates a new graph of type Graph[VertexState,Long] based on an
    input graph of type.
    * Graph[VD,Long].  The resulting graph can be used for louvain computation.
    *
    */
  def createLouvainGraph[VD: ClassTag](graph: Graph[VD, Long]):
  Graph[LouvainData, Long] = {
    val nodeWeights = graph.aggregateMessages(
      (e:EdgeContext[VD,Long,Long]) => {
        e.sendToSrc(e.attr)
        e.sendToDst(e.attr)
      },
      (e1: Long, e2: Long) => e1 + e2
    )

    graph.outerJoinVertices(nodeWeights)((vid, data, weightOption) => {
      val weight = weightOption.getOrElse(0L)
      new LouvainData(vid, weight, 0L, weight, false)
    }).partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.EdgePartition2D).groupEdges(_ + _)
  }

  /**
    * Creates the messages passed between each vertex to convey
    neighborhood community data.
    */
  def sendCommunityData(e: EdgeContext[LouvainData, Long, Map[(Long, Long), Long]]) = {
    val m1 = (Map((e.srcAttr.community, e.srcAttr.communitySigmaTot) -> e.attr))
    val m2 = (Map((e.dstAttr.community, e.dstAttr.communitySigmaTot) -> e.attr))
    e.sendToSrc(m2)
    e.sendToDst(m1)
  }

  /**
    * Merge neighborhood community data into a single message for each vertex
    */
  def mergeCommunityMessages(m1: Map[(Long, Long), Long], m2: Map[(Long, Long), Long]) = {
    val newMap = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[(Long, Long), Long]()

    m1.foreach({ case (k, v) =>
      if (newMap.contains(k)) newMap(k) = newMap(k) + v
      else newMap(k) = v
    })

    m2.foreach({ case (k, v) =>
      if (newMap.contains(k)) newMap(k) = newMap(k) + v
      else newMap(k) = v
    })

    newMap.toMap
  }

  /**
    * Returns the change in modularity that would result from a vertex
    moving to a specified community.
    */
  def q(
         currCommunityId: Long,
         testCommunityId: Long,
         testSigmaTot: Long,
         edgeWeightInCommunity: Long,
         nodeWeight: Long,
         internalWeight: Long,
         totalEdgeWeight: Long): BigDecimal = {

    val isCurrentCommunity = currCommunityId.equals(testCommunityId)
    val M = BigDecimal(totalEdgeWeight)
    val k_i_in_L = if (isCurrentCommunity) edgeWeightInCommunity + internalWeight else edgeWeightInCommunity
    val k_i_in = BigDecimal(k_i_in_L)
    val k_i = BigDecimal(nodeWeight + internalWeight)
    val sigma_tot = if (isCurrentCommunity) BigDecimal(testSigmaTot) - k_i else BigDecimal(testSigmaTot)

    var deltaQ = BigDecimal(0.0)

    if (!(isCurrentCommunity && sigma_tot.equals(BigDecimal.valueOf(0.0)))) {
      deltaQ = k_i_in - (k_i * sigma_tot / M)
      //println(s"      $deltaQ = $k_i_in - ( $k_i * $sigma_tot / $M")
    }

    deltaQ
  }

  /**
    * Join vertices with community data form their neighborhood and
    select the best community for each vertex to maximize change in
    modularity.
    * Returns a new set of vertices with the updated vertex state.
    */
  def louvainVertJoin(
                       louvainGraph: Graph[LouvainData, Long],
                       msgRDD: VertexRDD[Map[(Long, Long), Long]],
                       totalEdgeWeight: Broadcast[Long],
                       even: Boolean) = {

    // innerJoin[U, VD2](other: RDD[(VertexId, U)])(f: (VertexId, VD, U) => VD2): VertexRDD[VD2]
    louvainGraph.vertices.innerJoin(msgRDD)((vid, louvainData, communityMessages) => {

      var bestCommunity = louvainData.community
      val startingCommunityId = bestCommunity
      var maxDeltaQ = BigDecimal(0.0);
      var bestSigmaTot = 0L

      // VertexRDD[scala.collection.immutable.Map[(Long, Long),Long]]
      // e.g. (1,Map((3,10) -> 2, (6,4) -> 2, (2,8) -> 2, (4,8) -> 2, (5,8) -> 2))
      // e.g. communityId:3, sigmaTotal:10, communityEdgeWeight:2
      communityMessages.foreach({ case ((communityId, sigmaTotal), communityEdgeWeight) =>
        val deltaQ = q(
          startingCommunityId,
          communityId,
          sigmaTotal,
          communityEdgeWeight,
          louvainData.nodeWeight,
          louvainData.internalWeight,
          totalEdgeWeight.value)

        //println(" communtiy: "+communityId+" sigma:"+sigmaTotal+"
        //edgeweight:"+communityEdgeWeight+" q:"+deltaQ)
        if (deltaQ > maxDeltaQ || (deltaQ > 0 && (deltaQ == maxDeltaQ &&
          communityId > bestCommunity))) {
          maxDeltaQ = deltaQ
          bestCommunity = communityId
          bestSigmaTot = sigmaTotal
        }
      })

      // only allow changes from low to high communties on even cyces and
      // high to low on odd cycles
      if (louvainData.community != bestCommunity && ((even &&
        louvainData.community > bestCommunity) || (!even &&
        louvainData.community < bestCommunity))) {
        //println("  "+vid+" SWITCHED from "+vdata.community+" to "+bestCommunity)
        louvainData.community = bestCommunity
        louvainData.communitySigmaTot = bestSigmaTot
        louvainData.changed = true
      }
      else {
        louvainData.changed = false
      }

      if (louvainData == null)
        println("vdata is null: " + vid)

      louvainData
    })
  }

  def louvain(
               sc: SparkContext,
               graph: Graph[LouvainData, Long],
               minProgress: Int = 1,
               progressCounter: Int = 1): (Double, Graph[LouvainData, Long], Int) = {

    var louvainGraph = graph.cache()

    val graphWeight = louvainGraph.vertices.map(louvainVertex => {
      val (vertexId, louvainData) = louvainVertex
      louvainData.internalWeight + louvainData.nodeWeight
    }).reduce(_ + _)

    val totalGraphWeight = sc.broadcast(graphWeight)

    println("totalEdgeWeight: " + totalGraphWeight.value)

    // gather community information from each vertex's local neighborhood
    var communityRDD =
      louvainGraph.aggregateMessages(sendCommunityData, mergeCommunityMessages)

    var activeMessages = communityRDD.count() //materializes the msgRDD
    //and caches it in memory
    var updated = 0L - minProgress
    var even = false
    var count = 0
    val maxIter = 100000
    var stop = 0
    var updatedLastPhase = 0L
    do {
      count += 1
      even = !even

      // label each vertex with its best community based on neighboring
      // community information
      val labeledVertices = louvainVertJoin(louvainGraph, communityRDD,
        totalGraphWeight, even).cache()

      // calculate new sigma total value for each community (total weight
      // of each community)
      val communityUpdate = labeledVertices
        .map({ case (vid, vdata) => (vdata.community, vdata.nodeWeight +
          vdata.internalWeight)})
        .reduceByKey(_ + _).cache()

      // map each vertex ID to its updated community information
      val communityMapping = labeledVertices
        .map({ case (vid, vdata) => (vdata.community, vid)})
        .join(communityUpdate)
        .map({ case (community, (vid, sigmaTot)) => (vid, (community, sigmaTot))})
        .cache()

      // join the community labeled vertices with the updated community info
      val updatedVertices = labeledVertices.join(communityMapping).map({
        case (vertexId, (louvainData, communityTuple)) =>
          val (community, communitySigmaTot) = communityTuple
          louvainData.community = community
          louvainData.communitySigmaTot = communitySigmaTot
          (vertexId, louvainData)
      }).cache()

      updatedVertices.count()
      labeledVertices.unpersist(blocking = false)
      communityUpdate.unpersist(blocking = false)
      communityMapping.unpersist(blocking = false)

      val prevG = louvainGraph

      louvainGraph = louvainGraph.outerJoinVertices(updatedVertices)((vid, old, newOpt) => newOpt.getOrElse(old))
      louvainGraph.cache()

      // gather community information from each vertex's local neighborhood
      val oldMsgs = communityRDD
      communityRDD = louvainGraph.aggregateMessages(sendCommunityData, mergeCommunityMessages).cache()
      activeMessages = communityRDD.count() // materializes the graph
      // by forcing computation

      oldMsgs.unpersist(blocking = false)
      updatedVertices.unpersist(blocking = false)
      prevG.unpersistVertices(blocking = false)

      // half of the communites can swtich on even cycles and the other half
      // on odd cycles (to prevent deadlocks) so we only want to look for
      // progess on odd cycles (after all vertcies have had a chance to
      // move)
      if (even) updated = 0
      updated = updated + louvainGraph.vertices.filter(_._2.changed).count

      if (!even) {
        println("  # vertices moved: " + java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance().format(updated))

        if (updated >= updatedLastPhase - minProgress) stop += 1

        updatedLastPhase = updated
      }

    } while (stop <= progressCounter && (even || (updated > 0 && count < maxIter)))

    println("\nCompleted in " + count + " cycles")

    // Use each vertex's neighboring community data to calculate the
    // global modularity of the graph
    val newVertices =
    louvainGraph.vertices.innerJoin(communityRDD)((vertexId, louvainData,
                                                   communityMap) => {
      // sum the nodes internal weight and all of its edges that are in
      // its community
      val community = louvainData.community
      var accumulatedInternalWeight = louvainData.internalWeight
      val sigmaTot = louvainData.communitySigmaTot.toDouble
      def accumulateTotalWeight(totalWeight: Long, item: ((Long, Long), Long)) = {
        val ((communityId, sigmaTotal), communityEdgeWeight) = item
        if (louvainData.community == communityId)
          totalWeight + communityEdgeWeight
        else
          totalWeight
      }

      accumulatedInternalWeight = communityMap.foldLeft(accumulatedInternalWeight)(accumulateTotalWeight)
      val M = totalGraphWeight.value
      val k_i = louvainData.nodeWeight + louvainData.internalWeight
      val q = (accumulatedInternalWeight.toDouble / M) - ((sigmaTot * k_i) / math.pow(M, 2))
      //println(s"vid: $vid community: $community $q = ($k_i_in / $M) - ( ($sigmaTot * $k_i) / math.pow($M, 2) )")
      if (q < 0)
        0
      else
        q
    })

    val actualQ = newVertices.values.reduce(_ + _)

    // return the modularity value of the graph along with the
    // graph. vertices are labeled with their community
    (actualQ, louvainGraph, count / 2)

  }

  def compressGraph(graph: Graph[LouvainData, Long], debug: Boolean = true): Graph[LouvainData, Long] = {
    // aggregate the edge weights of self loops. edges with both src and dst in the same community.
    // WARNING  can not use graph.mapReduceTriplets because we are mapping to new vertexIds
    val internalEdgeWeights = graph.triplets.flatMap(et => {
      if (et.srcAttr.community == et.dstAttr.community) {
        Iterator((et.srcAttr.community, 2 * et.attr)) // count the weight from both nodes
      }
      else Iterator.empty
    }).reduceByKey(_ + _)

    // aggregate the internal weights of all nodes in each community
    val internalWeights = graph.vertices.values.map(vdata =>
      (vdata.community, vdata.internalWeight))
      .reduceByKey(_ + _)

    // join internal weights and self edges to find new interal weight of each community
    val newVertices = internalWeights.leftOuterJoin(internalEdgeWeights).map({ case (vid, (weight1, weight2Option)) =>
      val weight2 = weight2Option.getOrElse(0L)
      val state = new LouvainData()
      state.community = vid
      state.changed = false
      state.communitySigmaTot = 0L
      state.internalWeight = weight1 + weight2
      state.nodeWeight = 0L
      (vid, state)
    }).cache()

    // translate each vertex edge to a community edge
    val edges = graph.triplets.flatMap(et => {
      val src = math.min(et.srcAttr.community, et.dstAttr.community)
      val dst = math.max(et.srcAttr.community, et.dstAttr.community)
      if (src != dst) Iterator(new Edge(src, dst, et.attr))
      else Iterator.empty
    }).cache()

    // generate a new graph where each community of the previous graph is
    // now represented as a single vertex
    val compressedGraph = Graph(newVertices, edges)
      .partitionBy(PartitionStrategy.EdgePartition2D).groupEdges(_ + _)

    // calculate the weighted degree of each node
    val nodeWeights = compressedGraph.aggregateMessages(
      (e:EdgeContext[LouvainData,Long,Long]) => {
        e.sendToSrc(e.attr)
        e.sendToDst(e.attr)
      },
      (e1: Long, e2: Long) => e1 + e2
    )

    // fill in the weighted degree of each node
    // val louvainGraph = compressedGraph.joinVertices(nodeWeights)((vid,data,weight)=> {
    val louvainGraph = compressedGraph.outerJoinVertices(nodeWeights)((vid, data, weightOption) => {
      val weight = weightOption.getOrElse(0L)
      data.communitySigmaTot = weight + data.internalWeight
      data.nodeWeight = weight
      data
    }).cache()
    louvainGraph.vertices.count()
    louvainGraph.triplets.count() // materialize the graph

    newVertices.unpersist(blocking = false)
    edges.unpersist(blocking = false)


    println("******************************************************")
    println (louvainGraph.vertices.count())

    louvainGraph

  }

  def saveLevel(
                 sc: SparkContext,
                 config: LouvainConfig,
                 level: Int,
                 qValues: Array[(Int, Double)],
                 graph: Graph[LouvainData, Long]) = {

    val vertexSavePath = config.outputDir + "/level_" + level + "_vertices"
    val edgeSavePath = config.outputDir + "/level_" + level + "_edges"

    // save
    graph.vertices.saveAsTextFile(vertexSavePath)
    graph.edges.saveAsTextFile(edgeSavePath)

    // overwrite the q values at each level
    sc.parallelize(qValues, 1).saveAsTextFile(config.outputDir + "/qvalues_" + level)
  }

  //def run[VD: ClassTag](sc: SparkContext, config: LouvainConfig, graph: Graph[VD, Long]): Unit = {
  def run[VD: ClassTag](sc: SparkContext, config: LouvainConfig): Unit = {
    val edgeRDD = getEdgeRDD(sc, config)
    val initialGraph = Graph.fromEdges(edgeRDD, None)
    var louvainGraph = createLouvainGraph(initialGraph)

    var compressionLevel = -1 // number of times the graph has been compressed
    var q_modularityValue = -1.0 // current modularity value
    var halt = false

    var qValues: Array[(Int, Double)] = Array()

    do {
      compressionLevel += 1
      println(s"\nStarting Louvain level $compressionLevel")

      // label each vertex with its best community choice at this level of compression
      val (currentQModularityValue, currentGraph, numberOfPasses) =
        louvain(sc, louvainGraph, config.minimumCompressionProgress, config.progressCounter)

      louvainGraph.unpersistVertices(blocking = false)
      louvainGraph = currentGraph

      println(s"qValue: $currentQModularityValue")

      qValues = qValues :+ ((compressionLevel, currentQModularityValue))

      saveLevel(sc, config, compressionLevel, qValues, louvainGraph)

      // If modularity was increased by at least 0.001 compress the graph and repeat
      // halt immediately if the community labeling took less than 3 passes
      //println(s"if ($passes > 2 && $currentQ > $q + 0.001 )")
      if (numberOfPasses > 2 && currentQModularityValue > q_modularityValue + 0.001) {
        q_modularityValue = currentQModularityValue
        louvainGraph = compressGraph(louvainGraph)
      }
      else {
        halt = true
      }

    } while (!halt)
    //finalSave(sc, compressionLevel, q_modularityValue, louvainGraph)


  }
}
```

The code is taken from [github https://github.com/athinggoingon/louvain-modularity](https://github.com/athinggoingon/louvain-modularity).

Here is the example of input file, just first 10 lines. The graph is made from csv file, schema is : node1, node2, weight_of_the_edge

```
104,158,34.23767571520276
146,242,12.49338107205348
36,37,0.6821403413414481
28,286,2.5053934980726456
9,92,0.34412941554076487
222,252,10.502288293870677
235,282,0.25717021769814874
264,79,18.555996343792327
24,244,1.7094102023399587
231,75,21.698401383558213
```

Comment: Maybe one has a bug? You ask us to speculate what code does that we don't know?

Comment: Maybe one is giving the hierarchy overview level and the other one is giving clustering on the full graph? Do both results have the same number of vertices in the final result?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse : I was interested if someone had similar issue when running something with Spark/Scala vs. python/c#. Any hint about what could possible be reason for such behavior (excluding the bug possibility) would be helpful.

Comment: @Pallie : What do you mean by hierarchy overview level? Did you have similar situation with any graph clustering algorithm?

Comment: @OliveraNovovic I doubt there is a systematic difference in the correctness of "something with Spark/Scala vs. Python/C#” that could cause a "similar issue", when we have neither your data, not your result, not your code and know little more than that you get different results... This is a bad question.

Comment: @OliveraNovović If I remember correctly, the original binaries published by Blondel give a tree structure as a result where the bottom of the tree has all nodes with a community assignment for each node, but further up the tree the graph gets summarized. If you look at a summarized level you will see fewer vertices than the full graph you started with. 300 nodes being divided into 50 communites does seem excessive. As Anony pointed out, it's hard to speculate without code/data examples.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse: Thank you for your comments. I edited the question, adding more details.

Comment: @Pallie: Thank you for your comments. I edited the question, adding more details. When I run Louvain in C# with 10000 nodes, it also makes small number of communities, around 11. Community detection over same graph in Spark produces around 150 communities. That confused me even more. From 300 nodes to ~10 communities is ok, but from 10000 to ~10 communities is strange.

Comment: There is a lot of buggy code on github... It's not as if this code appears to be particularly well tested and thoroughly reviewed - in fact, there is a report that it produces wrong results.